# Calculate probability of binary expansion $x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty X_n2^{-n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, binary

Let $x \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$ be a continuous uniform random variable

Then the binary expansion of $x$ is given by $$x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty X_n2^{-n}$$

I am required to find the probability that $X_1 = 0$, $X_2 = 0$, $X_1 = 1$, $X_2 = 0$.

*Attempt:*

Using equivalent events, we can express

$\Pr[X_1 = 0] = \Pr[0 \leq x \leq 1/2] = 1/2$

The second equality is true because $X_1 = 0$ implies that the sum $x$ can be at most $1/2$, and at least $0$ in the case that all $X_{n}$s' are zero.

Thus similarly,

$\Pr[X_2 = 0] = \Pr[0 \leq x \leq 3/4] = 3/4$

$\Pr[X_1 = 1] = \Pr[1/2 \leq x \leq 1] = 1/2$

$\Pr[X_2 = 1] = \Pr[1/4 \leq x \leq 1] = 3/4$

I evaluated those probabilities based on the length of the intervals and the fact that $x$ is uniform in $[0,1]$.

Can someone check if these probabilies are correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How's $\Pr[X_2 = 0] = \Pr[0 \leq x \leq 3/4] = 3/4$ ? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Since $x$ is a uniform random variable, therefore the density of $x$ is $f_x(\cdot) = 1$, and the integral from $0$ to $3/4$ is $3/4$ <- might be completely wrong though

Comment: The problem is: it's not true that $0\leq x \leq 3/4$ when $X_2=0$. Or rather, it's not sufficientlly narrowed down.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Please post your solution :)

Comment: @StackexchangeHouseNinja Please **think** about Rasko's very precise hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly wrong since $P(X_2=0)+P(X_2=1) >1$.

\begin{align}P(X_2=0)&=P(X_1=0, X_2=0)+P(X_1=1, X_2=0) \\
&=P\left(0 \leq X\leq \frac14\right)+P\left(\frac12 \leq X\leq \frac34\right)\end{align}

Comment: Hi can you pin point why I was wrong with $\Pr[X_2 = 0] = \Pr[0 \leq x \leq 3/4]$? Isn't it true that if $X_2 = 0$, then the maximum number we could have is $1 - 1/4 = 3/4$ and the minimum we could have is $0$?

Comment: How do you represent $0.3$ in binary?

Comment: $0.01001100110011001101$

Comment: Hence $X_2=1$ for $0.3$.

Comment: You were  not wrong that 0 is the minimum and 3/4 the maximum. What you were wrong about is that the set is just one interval going from that minimum to that maximum.